# Using the LinkedIn API to update a profile header/background image

Tags: linkedin-api

I am pretty new to the LinkedIn API. Does anyone know if there is a way to access a users profile header image/background image through the LinkedIn API? I have looked through the documentation and I cannot find it.

Also, if anyone has a good ASP.NET package that is built to work with LinkedIn so I don't have build the plumbing - would also love a recco.

Thanks.

JJO

## linkedin

Comment: SO is about programming and issues. Please provide some code or research, then you will have a bigger chance that someone will help.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I have been using SO for close to 20 years so I get how it works. LinkedIn - as a lot of the headless SAS providers are these days - are using Stackoverflow as official dev community (which we all know in modern times means support replacement - unfortunately). If you know of where I could better position this post to get in front of LinkedIn API experts, would love the feedback.

If there are any #linkedin employees on here - can you please jump in and assist?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't work with linkedin api. I see some github repo and its forks - https://github.com/SparkleNetworks/LinkedInNET, but probably you noticed it too.

Answer (score 1):

I found API documentation in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-edit-api?context=linkedin/compliance/context#background-picture

Unfortunately, it's a complex process with 3 stes:

1. Register the background picture image to be uploaded.

1.1  POST https://api.linkedin.com/v2/assets?action=registerUpload

```
{
  "registerUploadRequest": {
    "recipes": [
      "urn:li:digitalmediaRecipe:profile-originalbackground-image"
    ],
    "owner": "urn:li:person:ABCDEF",
    "serviceRelationships": []
  }
}
```

1.2  POST https://api.linkedin.com/v2/assets?action=registerUpload

```
{
  "registerUploadRequest": {
    "recipes": [
      "urn:li:digitalmediaRecipe:profile-displaybackground-image"
    ],
    "owner": "urn:li:person:ABCDEF",
    "serviceRelationships": []
  }
}
```

2. Upload the background picture image to LinkedIn.

`curl -i --upload-file /Users/peter/Desktop/superneatimage.png --header "Authorization: Bearer redacted" 'https://api.linkedin.com/mediaUpload/C5616AQEoeGkp7U5GEA/profile-uploadedBackgroundImage/0?ca=vector_profile&cn=uploads&m=AQIdKBw1WIgAWwAAAWhdlwvlhH13JEO0ZxBHb2VRuyAILbzD_VgJ-4UyLg&app=5480656&sync=0&v=beta&ut=1SpRkaq8G5DoA1'`

3. Update the member's profile.

Use the asset from Step 1 to update the profile with the new background picture.

```
{
  "patch": {
    "backgroundPicture": {
      "$set": {
        "originalImage": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C5604AQEMWf4Nl_mf2g",
        "displayImage": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C5616AQEoeGkp7U5GEA"
      }
    }
  }
}
```